# Error with a "Selection: " prompt

Tags: r

I have a weird recurring error and I am hoping to get some help here. The issue is that `R` would break into an error prompt (see below) whenever I refer to a nonexistent function the moment I type `(` following the incorrect function name (and before I even hit `enter`):

```
> asdf(
Selection:
```

The word `Selection` would be in purple (prompt color, as set in R preferences). At this point I have to enter `0` to go back to the regular prompt. Entering other numbers does not give any useful information as in `traceback`.

There are various ways that can lead to this. However, I have not been successful in replicating this from a `--vanilla` launch (while this suggests it's something with my profile, I haven't been able to isolate the cause). And even if I launch with my usual profile I would not see it when I first launch `R`, and it would take some time before this happens.

Once I see this error happens once, I would be able to consistent reproduce it until I restart R.

I can also trigger the error by selecting characters.

```
> xx <- 1
> xx
```

(right now the cursor is right behind the last `x` in `xx`) So far so good, but now if I try to select the last `x` (either by using the trackpad, or by pressing shift-left-arrow key) `R` would break into the same error.

In the status bar at the bottom of the `R` console window I would see

```
executing: try(gsub('\\s+','',paste(capture.output(print(args(x))),collapse='')),silent=TRUE)
```

I have R 3.2.2 on Mac OS X (10.11), but I have seen this error for a long time (I think more than a year).

While the error does not lead to any serious problems, it is very annoying. Anyone can give me some idea on how to fix this?

Comment: My first guess would be that you set `options(error=recover)` in your profile. You can check this by typing `options(error=NULL)` in your console and see if that fixes the issue.